# Passing data from promise then method to an object method

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, javascript-objects

How to pass `data` from promise `then` method to an object method.

```
this.httpReq(url).then(function (data) {
  this.storeData(data);
});
```

I know that here I'm out of scope and `this` doesn't refer to my object. But, nevertheless, I can't understand how to resolve it. 
Bellow you can find entire code snippet. 
In the end, I want to get data from the service API and store it in the object array property `this.storage`.

```
var http = require('http');

function CoubApi (url) {
  this.url = url;
  this.storage = [];
  this.httpReq = httpReq;
  this.searchData = searchData;
  this.storeData = storeData;
}

function httpReq (url) {
  var promise = new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {

    http.get(url, function (res) {
      var data = '';

      res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        data += chunk;
      });

      res.on('end', function () {
        if(data.length > 0) {
          resolve(JSON.parse(data));
        } else {
          reject("Error: HTTP request rejected!");
        }
      });

    }).on('error', function (err) {
      console.log("Error: ", e);
    });

  });

  return promise;
}

function storeData (data) {
  var i;
  console.log("Storrrreee");
  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    this.storage.push(data.coubs[i]);
  }
}

function searchData (searchtext, order, page) {
  var url = this.url+
            "search?q="+searchtext+
            "&order_by="+order+
            "&page="+page;


  this.httpReq(url).then(function (data) {
    this.storeData(data);
  });
}

var coub = new CoubApi("http://coub.com/api/v2/");
coub.searchData("cat", "newest_popular", 1);
console.log(coub.storage);
```

Comment: You could look into [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to bind the context of your promise `.then()` or use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this) which will capture the `this` of the enclosing context, so of `searchData`. That is assuming your browsers support arrow functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store this in varaible:

```
var self = this;
this.httpReq(url).then(function (data) {
  self.storeData(data);
});
```

or use bind:

```
this.httpReq(url).then(function (data) {
  this.storeData(data);
}.bind(this));
```